# Error when using pagePathPlusQueryString and dateHourMinute in the same GA4 Query

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

When I make a Query in GA4 in either the GA4 Query Explorer or the api via runReport using the dimensions pagePathPlusQueryString and dateHourMinute together I get an error saying.

Error: 400
Please remove dateHourMinute to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible
i was able to do this in V1

I was expecting to get the Date & Time a page with its query string.  It works with pagepath but not with pagePathPlusQueryString or FullPageURL.